# expertsoverflow.com clone of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

On Google search of *"sftp webjob azure"*, I found a link *"Newest 'azure' Questions - Stack Overflow - Top Questions"*, which I've thought to point to stackoverflow.com. Only after  I found myself not logged in and search box not working, I realized that I'm actually on domain expertsoverflow.com, which seems to clone Stack Overflow contents.

[image]

The domain expertsoverflow.com is registered to Ascio Technologies (ascio.com). So it does not seem to be related to Stack Exchange.

While I believe it's allowed to copy contents on Stack Overflow, I do not think they are allowed to copy the entire site, including the logo and the design. Am I right?

Comment: Judging by the fact that the site now redirects to a "too many requests" page which looks like it's directly served from stackoverflow.com, I guess the domain is simply acting as a (non-transparent) proxy for SO. No idea for what purpose, seems kind of useless...

Comment: I'm getting some security warnings when trying to open that page. This may be a phishing attempt: _"You are attempting to access www.expertsoverflow.com, but you reached a server that identifies as *.rhcloud.com..."_

Comment: It probably goes without saying that you shouldn't attempt to login to that site but, y'know, just in case - don't try.

Comment: `The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Comment: @JonK Actually I did try, just to see whether they try to steal my identity. But no, the "log in" points back to stackoverflow.

Comment: Not a bad name though. Who wouldn't be part of an expertsoverflow? Also makes all other SEs kind of redundant.

Comment: Looks very much like they're trying to phish logins.

Comment: @CashCow The same people behind [Pen Island Pens](http://www.penisland.net/)?

Comment: here phishy phishy...

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: yes, but via their proxy?

Comment: @RickyA: I mean "log in" link on the top bar, not "log in" button on the log in form. So no proxy.

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate of the linked post, voting to reopen.

Comment: Although this is a similar issue to the duplicate linked here, it is a different issue. If I could, I'd vote to reopen (and I would encourage others to do so)

Comment: @Bergi, It's not just a scraper, its an exact *clone*.

Comment: @Pacerier Semantics aside, the best way to report these to us is the same. :)

Comment: @Trilarion the important question is: do you want to be part of the overflow, or of the rest?

Comment: This is message I got...
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.expertsoverflow.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

Comment: Yes, we broke it!

Comment: Searching Google for the original term *"sftp webjob azure"* now returns this MSO question at the top of the results!

Comment: Why can't it be expertsexoverflow.com? You know, for people who used to be experiencing overflows. Of course. :-)

Comment: Wow, that's _really_ convincing. If I wasn't paying attention, I could easily mistake it for the real deal.

Comment: It's not proxying as changes/comments made on the real site are not appearing on the clone. Maybe a one off wget?

Comment: Note that if any of these scraping sites return a earlier search result than the original (SO) one, you can report them on the [Google Scraper Report](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Pw1KVOVRyr4a7ezj_6SHghnX1Y6bp1SOVmy60QjkF0Y/viewform). It's a lot of work and I don't know what Google does with it, but every negative attention sites like these get, is positive -)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Sites like that are why we can't have nice things... Except that we still can.

Please report it through the process outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) to make it easier for us to track this internally. Thanks!

Comment: I think this absolutely deserves its own question, and is nothing like an ordinary scraper. It looks like it might be a phishing scam, and needs investigating with far more urgency than a scraper would. They may well be trying to get users to enter login credentials they can use for mischief on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MarkAmery I don't dispute the urgency here.

Comment: Actually having tested all the links here their login redirects to SO directly, and so do many other things, it isn't scamming, it is just feeding Google ranking

Comment: Anybody knows why they are doing this? They don't seem to inject any ad and it's probably not that useful (at least financially) to phish SO logins. Could there be some legitimate use, like maybe a proxy for a country where SO is blocked?

Comment: @this.lau Maybe because some SO users don't use a SO specific login, but their facebook/yahoo/whatever accounts.

Comment: @this.lau_ One reason could be SEO weighting of SOs content, pay day loans people do this often with other sites togive theire own a boost since Google is not instant

Comment: @MarkAmery really, "mischief on Stack Overflow" is the bad case scenario here? I'd rather be worried about users who use their email/passwd combo on places that are "really" important. And if I were to open a big-scale fishing site, that'd be worth it, not all the hassle for some short-term spam.

Answer (score 61):

I did this. I have registered expertoverflow.com with an intention to build a simple stackoverflow proxy which would add a simple script obscuring answers and send the link to a few friends who remember the experts exchange terror and we would laugh ha ha. Maybe I would tweet it to my five followers and they would have a nicer start of their day.

As it happens, I did a simple proxy, went to bed with a good feeling of part1 done and next days totaly burried this with heavy workload, then i just forgot it.

Now someone indexed it, noticed it and I have a shiny letter from lawyers in my inbox yaay!

To conclude, I just took it down, I'll submit to all the law-things and repent. 
Rest assured there was no harmful code, no conspiracy to steal souls and certainly no ill intensions towards stackoverflow, as it is a developer's blessing.

End of story, good night.

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: I regret that my up vote merely grants you imaginary unicorn poo instead of something more substantial.  Congrats on an experiment going epically awry.

Comment: @tom,You managed to stump our entire company: "Can *anyone* figure out what their scam here is? NO? Oh, eff it - we'd better get the lawyers to stop if before we find out." But everyone enjoys a mystery, soo... I'm afraid we're running low on unicorn poo, but email me your mailing address and tee size. Confusing our lawyers probably deserves *some* kind of recognition. (jaydles@stackexchange.com)

Comment: Did you get the bees? https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/514059556549562368

Comment: I'm having a bad day, and this so made me smile, sometimes things just get epically out of hand during a good nap!  I'm empathetic to your pain, but thank you for sharing the story.